# When the user presses sign up, it keeps adding values to the database (MYSQL + PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I am starting to learn PHP. I just tried to make a signup.php page where the user (which is me) has a form and he fills the form and presses the sign up button, and then the values are saved in the database.

This code works perfectly fine in XAMPP. If an email already exists, it says clearly that the email already exists and the user is required to select a new username.
However, when I uploaded everything to cPanel on my website and tried to test it, I can keep pressing the sign up button and it will keep saying "successful" and when I check PhpMyAdmin, there are like 5 values of the same thing (because of the multiple clicks of the button).

So I don't really know what the problem is here. Any help is highly appreciated.

My current code:

```
<form  method='POST' class="form-login">
<?php



if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $fields = array(
    'Username' => $username,
    'Email' => $email
);

$dup = false;
foreach ($fields as $field => $value) {
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT({$field}) AS n FROM Users WHERE {$field}='{$value}';");
    $tuple = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    if ($tuple['n'] > 0) {
        $dup = true;
        break;
    }
    }



   if ($dup) {
        echo "<p><b><center> <font color=\"red\">{$field} already exists.<br> </b>If you already have an account, please<a href = 'login.php'> click here </a> to login.</font></center></p>"; 
    }

else {

        $regdate=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$username', '$password', '$email', '1', '0', '2', '$IP', '$regdate', '', 'active')");

<label>First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="<?=(isset($first_name) ? $first_name : "")?>"/>
    <label>Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="<?=(isset($last_name) ? $last_name : "")?>"/>



<label>Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?=(isset($username) ? $username : "")?>"/>

<label for="email">
    Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="<?=(isset($email) ? $email :"")?>"/>

 <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="<?=(isset($password) ? $password : "")?>"/>
        <button type="submit" name="submit"  value="Register">Register</button>

</form>
```

Comment: you could create unique key based on username and email column

Comment: I prefer just checking if the data already exists in the database.

Comment: Why are you looping the fields array.. can you not achieve this in a single query like this: "Select count(id) from users where username='{$username}' or email = '{$email}' "

Comment: Also can you check if you are getting anything $_POST['submit']...since its not going inside the if section...also try replacing the <button type="submit"> .. with <input type="submit">